# feedback on way to set PHP class only once

Tags: php, oop

and would like to work with them effectively.  Here is the premise for an application I am doing:

1. we only need to instantiate a class once
2. I don't know necessarily if the class has been instantiated
3. If I ever need to instantiate a class multiple times, I'll have enough common sense not to use this system
4. the class could be called in another class, function etc., but once called I want it to be available anywhere

that said here is a function I am working on.  It allows a class to be set, once, and be available globally anywhere.  But it seems very clumsy and and I think there must be improvements in it:

```
            function set_class_once(){
                //example of most complex use: set_class_once('ClassA',$a [array], '$ginger', 'string');
                $args=func_get_args();
                if(!count($args))return;
                $i=0;
                $class='';
                foreach($args as $n=>$v){
                    $i++;
                    if(!$class){
                        $class=$v; //always a string
                        unset($args[$n]); //remove from $args
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(is_array($v)){
                        $temp[$i]=$v;
                        $args[$n]='$temp['.$i.']'; //re-task
                    }else if(substr($v,0,1)=='$' && substr($v,1,7)!='GLOBALS'){
                        $args[$n]='$GLOBALS[\''.str_replace('$','',$v).'\']'; //variable
                    }else{
                        $args[$n]='\''.addslashes($v).'\'';         
                    }
                }
                if(isset($GLOBALS[$class]) && is_object($GLOBALS[$class])){
                    //OK, we've instantiated that class
                }else if(!class_exists($class)){
                    //fatal error
                    exit('Class '.$class.' does not exist');
                }else{
                    print_r('$GLOBALS[$class]=new '.$class.'('.(!empty($args)?implode(',',$args):'').');').'<br>';
                    eval('$GLOBALS[$class]=new '.$class.'('.(!empty($args)?implode(',',$args):'').');');
                }
            }

            class ClassC{
                function ClassC($param1,$param2,$param3){
                    echo 'here is param1:<br>';
                    print_r($param1);
                    echo 'here is param2:<br>';
                    print_r($param2);
                    echo 'here is param3:<br>';
                    print_r($param3);
                }
            }


            //with no params passed set_class_once('ClassA');
            //with params passed:
            $a=array(
                'apple'=>'red',
                'spinach'=>'green',
            );
            $ginger='fred backwards';
            set_class_once('ClassC',$a,'$ginger','string');
```

Comment: [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to the rescue!

Comment: @kingkero, I may not be able to do an extends condition with Singleton as given below - so could still use critique on the instantiation method above

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI

Answer (score -1):

Build yourself a simple *singleton* and extend it for the classes that you want to have only 1 instance:

```
class Singleton
{
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        static $instance = null;

        if (null === $instance) {
            $instance = new static();
        }    
        return $instance;
    }

    protected function __construct() { }
}

class ClassC extends Singleton
{
}
```

Then:

```
$object = ClassC::getInstance();
```

Not sure that I follow the args logic, but I'm sure there is a better practice for what you are attempting.  Maybe create these with a *factory* class?

Comment: Shouldn't the attribute be defined outside the method and `new static()` be `new self`?

Comment: so what I understand is, if I specify:
    $object= ClassC::getInstance();
TWICE, then ClassC will NOT be instantiated twice, correct?  Sorry I'm new to OOP and don't know enough to fully evaluate just yet

Comment: Also, great example of a [Yoda condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

Comment: hope I'm not overcommenting here but the $args allows me to pass set_class_once() with 1 or more arguments.  The first argument is the class namespace, and the subsequent arguments would be passed to the class, if and in whatever way the class is expecting to receive them.  Obvs. seems very clunky.  BUT, it works as desired and doesn't require mods to any of the classes we have